# Show that $\int_{(0,1)\times (0,1)} \frac{1}{1-xy} dxdy = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, integration, definite-integrals

I'm looking for a clever way to show that
$$ \int\limits_{(0,1)\times (0,1)} \frac{1}{1-xy} dxdy = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}.$$
All suggestions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** $$\frac{1}{1-xy}=1+(xy)+(xy)^2+....$$
then integrate term by term.

(This is not a full solution though and there are some important details that must be included in order to have a rigorous argument)

Comment: nice, thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 This is a very nice hint and the integration term-by-term, which also appears in my answer, is very beautiful.

Answer (score 6):

The integral is

$$\int\limits_0^1dx\int\limits_0^1\frac1{1-xy}dy=-\int\limits_0^1\left.\frac1x\log(1-xy)\right|_0^1dx=-\int\limits_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)}xdx=$$

$$=\int\limits_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\left.\frac{x^n}n\right|_0^1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}$$

Can you justify all the steps above...?